# Radius of convergence of power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}x^{6n+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, power-series, alternative-proof

> Find radius of convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{6n+2}}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}}$.

My try:

Using Cauchy's Root test for convergence $\displaystyle \lim_nsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}|(z-c)|<1$, we get

$\displaystyle \lim_nsup \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{1}{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{n^2}}\right|}\,|x^6|<1\implies \lim_nsup \frac{1}{\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{n}}|x|^6<1$. Hence $|x|^6<{e}$ or

the interval of convergence is $\displaystyle \Big(-e^\frac{1}{6},e^\frac{1}{6}\Big)$ and radius of convergence is $2e^\frac{1}{6}$. Am I correct ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the intervall of convergence is $\displaystyle \Big(-e^\frac{1}{6},e^\frac{1}{6}\Big)$, is correct. But the radius of convergence is $e^\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: ok yeah ! I calculated the length of the interval. Thanks @Fred.